# GetAsyncKeyState works for me, but not on my friends computer? How can I fix?

Tags: c#

For a program that I'm making it has a loop on a seperate thread that checks for a key being presses using GetAsyncKeyState, this seems to work fine for me and couple friends but one friend it doesnt work for... I have looked at his keyboard language settings they seem right but i cant work out why my program cant detect his key presses.

Tried changing languages of keyboard, tried on screen keyboard and tried using ('o') rather than the ascii number for the letter o

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(79) > 0)
{
    if (gunDelay < 5000)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        gunDelay = gunDelay + 30;
        Delegate rateFire = new Delegate(RateofFire);
        this.Invoke(rateFire);
        gunDelayChange = true;
    }
}
```

Should work just as mine does, changing the value yet his always breaks, this is the exact same program nothing different as mine.

Comment: Could be a security setting or software blocking it. Software that is constantly checking the state of the keyboard is sometimes viewed as malicious activity (such as a keylogger). Afterall, something like that could be used to, say, listen for usernames and passwords as they're typed into a web browser.

Comment: If this is for a game that is or can be fullscreen then `GetAsyncKeyState()` won't work. If that's the case you need to look into implementing a _Low-level Keyboard hook_ instead. Apart from that, you're also not checking it correctly. To check whether the key is actually being pushed down (and not in a transition state, etc.) you need to do: `if(GetAsyncKeyState(79) & 0x8000 == 0x8000)`.